# What is the difference between getFilesDir() and getFileAbsolutePath()

Tags: android

When I use either of them, I get the same result. It's just that to use `getFileAbsolutePath`,  I use a file object.

```
Log.v("getFilesDir", "" + getFilesDir().toString());
file = getFilesDir();
Log.v("file.getAbsolutePath",""+file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Result:

> V/getFilesDir﹕ /data/data/com.kingbell.interprocesscommunication_simple/files
>
> V/file.getAbsolutePath﹕/data/data/com.kingbell.interprocesscommunication_simple/files

Comment: they are both absolute path of your `file`, no difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in android docs.

**getFilesDir()**

Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where files created with openFileOutput(String, int) are stored.

This means that it returns a File Object, A File could represent files or directories, in this case a directory. you can check it by calling the **isDirectory()** method.

**getAbsolutePath()**

Returns the absolute path of this file.

This is the path of this file, but rememeber that directories are represented with the same file objects just like a real file. you can verify it by checking the **isDirectory()** or **isFile()** method.

So, in your case they point to the same place.

You called getFilesDir(), so your context give you a directory represented in an instance of the File class. In that file object you call getAbsolutePath() so they represent the same thing, since this is an actual directory.

Clear?

Comment: I understood the isDirectory() and isFile() method explanation, but I still don't understand the difference between getAbsolutePath() and getFilesDirectory() can you please explain with an example ??? According to my understanding getFilesDirectory() - returns path of the directory in which the file is written using OpenFileOutput() and getAbsolutePath() gives you full path am I right ?

Comment: what is exactly your doubt?

Comment: They both return the same path so what is the difference between them? is it that getFilesDirectory() returns the path of the directory and getAbsolutePath() returns the path of the directory so we are not sure whether the file object contains a file or a directory so we use isDirectory or isFile to check. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes. getFilesDir return the directory.. but there is no class to represent a directory only file class. so the class file can represent a folder or a file. so once you call  file = getFilesDir(), your recive a file object that is a directory representation that points to /data/data/com.kingbell.interprocesscommunication_simple/files.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be more clear with the source code.

getAbsolutePath()

```
package java.io.file

public class File {

   public String  getAbsolutePath() {

         return fs.resolve(this);
   }
}
```

and getFilesDir()

```
package android.content

public abstract class Context {

public abstract File getFilesDir();

}
```

and for a specific Context(typically is an activity), the return value for the getFilesDir() call is fixed and should be always same, it tells you a location you can use to save your file.

At the same time, you can call getAbsolutePath() on any File object to get a full file path, either the file created by you or the file carried in an URI sent to you.

That is why these two calls are in the different packages.

Hope the explanation helps.